# concate or segregate strings based on requirement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-concatenation, listagg

```
USER_ID     COLUMN1       COLUMN2

JOHN          24           CA
JOHN          24           LA
JOHN          63           CA
JOHN          63           LA
JOHN          66           CA
JOHN          66           LA
JOHN           9           AF
JOHN           9           AL
JOHN           9           AW
JOHN           9           DF
```

Required output:

```
USER_ID          RESULT

JOHN             24~CA-LA  +  63~CA-LA  + 66~CA-LA +  9~AF-AL-AW-DF
```

This is my requirement. I am trying `listagg()`:

```
select USER_ID,
   (listagg(case when seqnum_p = 1 then COLUMN1 end, '-') within group (order by COLUMN1) ||
    '~' ||
    listagg(case when seqnum_b = 1 then COLUMN2 end, '-') within group (order by COLUMN2)
   ) as result
from (select TABLE.*,
         row_number() over (partition by USER_ID, COLUMN1 order by COLUMN1) as seqnum_p,
         row_number() over (partition by USER_ID, COLUMN2 order by COLUMN2) as seqnum_b
  from TABLE
 )
group by USER_ID;
```

Current output:

```
JOHN         ||       AF-AL-AW-CA-DF-LA~24-63-66-9
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free pump-and-dump  code writing service.

Comment: :) yes select USER_ID,
       (listagg(case when seqnum_p = 1 then COLUMN1 end, '-') within group (order by COLUMN1) ||
        '~' ||
        listagg(case when seqnum_b = 1 then OFFICE_CODE end, '-') within group (order by OFFICE_CODE)
       ) as result
from (select TABLE.*,
             row_number() over (partition by USER_ID, COLUMN1 order by COLUMN1) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by USER_ID, OFFICE_CODE order by OFFICE_CODE) as seqnum_b
      from TABLE
     )
group by USER_ID;      @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i can able to segregate but not fitting my correct requirement @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please add that as formatted code in your question ,and explain what was wrong with it - errors, wrong results, etc. And then remove the comment version.

Comment: yes, explained @AlexPoole

Comment: sorry for spell mistake.. now it is clear @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two levels of aggregation instead of dealing with the row numbers:

```
select user_id,
  listagg(tmp, ' + ') within group (order by tmp) as result
from (
  select user_id,
    column1 ||'~'|| listagg(column2, '-') within group (order by column2) as tmp
  from your_table
  group by user_id, column1
)
group by user_id
order by user_id;

USER RESULT                                            
---- --------------------------------------------------
JOHN 24~CA-LA + 63~CA-LA + 66~CA-LA + 9~AF-AL-AW-DF
```

The inner query gives you the first level:

```
USER TMP                                               
---- --------------------------------------------------
JOHN 9~AF-AL-AW-DF                                     
JOHN 24~CA-LA                                          
JOHN 63~CA-LA                                          
JOHN 66~CA-LA
```

and the outer level further aggregates those into a single string per user.

The order-by in the outer query aggregation is of a string starting with a number, which puts `'9~...'` after `'24~...'`, which would normally be odd but seems to be what you expect.

If you actually wanted them in numerical column-1-order you can include that in the subquery and use it for ordering:

```
select user_id,
  listagg(tmp, ' + ') within group (order by column1) as result
from (
  select user_id, column1,
    column1 ||'~'|| listagg(column2, '-') within group (order by column2) as tmp
  from your_table
  group by user_id, column1
)
group by user_id
order by user_id;

USER RESULT                                            
---- --------------------------------------------------
JOHN 9~AF-AL-AW-DF + 24~CA-LA + 63~CA-LA + 66~CA-LA
```